# How to update Java swing background drawings?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, event-handling, draw

[image]

[image]

As you see these picture, the background grid lines and black rectangle are not updated after the menu item is closed. How can I update it? In C# there is an event handler to make it updated automatically, but I am newbie to Java swing GUI application.

Here is the code:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {

  super.paintComponents(g); 

  MainDisplayForm mD = new MainDisplayForm();           


  Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;  

  g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
  int gridWidth = 1240;
  int gridHeight = 400;      
  g2.fillRect(20, 50, gridWidth, gridHeight);


  g2.setColor(Color.darkGray);

  paintGrid(g2,gridWidth, gridHeight);

  g2.setColor(Color.red);
  Line2D line = new Line2D.Float(20, 50, 250, 260);               
  g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
  //g2.draw(line); //pending       

  g2.dispose();

}

private void paintGrid(Graphics g, int gridWidth, int gridHeight)
{

  for(int i=20; i<gridWidth+20; i=i+10)
  {      
      g.drawLine(i, 50, i, gridHeight+49);          
  }      

  for(int i=50; i<gridHeight+50; i=i+10)
  {      
      g.drawLine(20, i, 1259, i);          
  }      
}
```

//Thanks for comments!! Here is the event handler to add. 
   **This must be added to every memu item drawn over the grid**

```
private void jMenu2MenuDeselected(javax.swing.event.MenuEvent evt) {
    repaint();
}
```

Comment: `MainDisplayForm mD = new MainDisplayForm();`  What is that line of code supposed to do?  Generally, you should not be creating components in a `paint()` or `paintComponent()` method.  What is a `MainDisplayForm`?  And to reiterate what camickr mentioned, for better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the menu is closed call reprint to the window.

Don't call `paint(getGraphics())`. Instead call `repaint()` because this informs the super component that it needs to redraw as well.

Comment: Is that MenuCanceled(javax.swing.event.MenuEvent evt)?

Comment: I have never had this problem but I guess it would be that and something like menu accepted or selected. You would have to implement both So it would redraw both when it is cancelled and when the menu is closed because the user selected something.

Comment: Thanks!!! It was MenuDeselected(javax.swing.event.MenuEvent evt)!!! Now, it works fine with repaint() in it.

Comment: -1, There is no need to invoke repaint() when a menu closes. You have some other problem.

Answer (score 6):

Don't override paint() and invoke super.paintComponents().

Custom painting is done by overriding the paintComponent() method of a JPanel (or JComponent) and then you would invoke super.paintComponent().

If you need more help then post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @user1098761 this isn't any form of comments

Comment: I have tried to invoke super.paintComponents() with repaint(). This also solved the some blinking problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use `repaint()` for refreshing/updating the components.

**When to use `repaint()`?**

After you add some components to a panel/frame or manipulate some components, for example when you change the locations/properties of components in a Swing animation, call `repaint()` and it will do the job for you. Actually, it triggers a call for `update()` method of the calling component.

Comment: I had tried it already but it draws the menu item behind the rectangle and draw it again. I created an event handler on menu and mouse move event on screen but I wonder the event handler I used is not the one you mention. Thx.

Comment: @user1098761 What did you try? Can you add some code to your post showing where you used repaint() ?

Comment: I had tried some different event handler. Now it works fine with MenuDeselected(javax.swing.event.MenuEvent evt). Thanks!